Need Python code for create table and chart
I need to create a Python code that analyzes an Excel file and extracts the following three pieces of information:

Female-owned businesses in Italy from 2014 to 2024.
The top 5 ATECO codes with the highest number of women in these 10 years.
From 2014 to 2024, the 5 regions with the most female-owned businesses and the 5 with the fewest, along with their trends over time.
The file contains in the first column the various values broken down by ATECO code, first for Italy as a whole, then for each province, and finally for each region.
In the second column, the various ATECO codes from A to X are listed, and from the third column onward, the number of active female-owned businesses per quarter. I would like to extract only the data as of 31/12 for each year.

I expect the code to generate a table and a chart for each point, showing the trend from 2014 to 2024.
